# Neo4j AWS Browser Connection Working for One instance, not another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I have two Neo4j instances at AWS EC2. The second was created from the first and all port permissions were replicated. I can access and log in to the original using my FireFox browser. When I try to connect to the 2nd instance, I get asked to login. I use the instance ID for the second instance but get an error message:

> ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security
>   constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not
>   available to this Neo4j Driver.

Why does the connection work for one and not the other instance? What is the fix?